# IPTables Range of Ports

Tags: centos, iptables

Hey guys in my iptables file I have the following line:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 20000:25000 -j ACCEPT
```

Because I'm trying to open a range of ports that will need to be open for multiple (Yes THAT many multiple) different minecraft servers.

I know the issue is the IPTables because when I stopped them, I was able to get on the server (Port 20004) But with them on, I can't connect, did I format it right? I even did just

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 20004 -j ACCEPT
```

The second one copying the exact SSH port 22 rule, except the port obviously, any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you issue an

```
-F INPUT
```

first, if relevant?

You have asked for ideas.  If you've not tried this one, you might.  IPtables bugs sometimes are not trivial to isolate, are they?   However, it can help if you start from a known state, which the `-F` achieves.

Good luck.

Comment: It gave me an error when I changed the line to have -F infront of it, I guess im confussed at where that goes? P.s. I'm running CentOS 6

Comment: Right.  To `-F INPUT` is the whole line (that is, the line is not `-F INPUT -m state`, etc., but just `-F INPUT`).  For now, keep the full `-A` line you already have, only precede it by the the shorter `-F INPUT` line.  Will this solve your problem?  Answer:  maybe, but probably not by itself.  However, it may *help* to solve your problem because it eliminates the irritating possibility that your error were due to some unknown, pre-existing state in `INPUT`.  It clears `INPUT` before your `-A` sets it.

Comment: I do not claim to be an expert in the matter, incidentally.  I only answered because I knew something that might be useful and because I didn't see any other answers here at the time.  Maybe, once you solve the problem, you will post your own answer here, better than my answer.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the above rule

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --match multiport --dports 20000:25000 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

#iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dports 20000:25000 -j ACCEPT